# python-why AttributeError: 'case' object has no attribute 'account'

Tags: attributeerror

```
import unittest
from SFDC_Objects.Accounts import Accounts

class case(unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.account=Accounts()
        self.account.account_init()

    def testcase(self):
        self.account.login()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.account.account_destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup method is called `setUp`. `setup` means nothing to `unittest`, so it isn't called, so the initialization doesn't happen. Rename `setup` to `setUp`.

Also, this test won't test anything, as `testcase` should be called `runTest`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quikly answer it help me but i want to ask another question how do i define extends from unittest without define unittest structure?